# Converting Charector to DateTime

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a dataframe called sleepDay with a variable SleepDay such as below:

[image: The dataframe]

I tried converting sleepDay to dmy_hms using lubridate but some values are returning NA.

```
sleepDay <- mutate(sleepDay, ActivityDate = dmy_hms(SleepDay))
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your actual data nor the image clearly shows the data. So I don't know if you have only dates in the data or both date and time.

Nonetheless, the format in your data is Month/Date/Year so use `mdy_hms` if you have both date and time in the data or `mdy` if you have only dates.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sleepDay <- mutate(sleepDay, ActivityDate = mdy_hms(SleepDay))
```